# Can Java EE 7's core interfaces (EntityManager, ...) extend AutoClosable?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

I've wondered about, will [Java EE 7's](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=342) core interfaces extends [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) or not. (By *core interfaces* I primarily mean [`EntityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) and the likes, however I don't know for sure if there are other interfaces or classes that could potentially be closed automatically.)

I think they *should* and here is the basis of my assumption.

[Java 6's `Connection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) doesn't even extend [`Closeable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html), however [Java 7's `Connection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) extends `AutoCloseable` (just like several other interfaces in the [java.sql](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) package).

Can interfaces like `EntityManager` extend `AutoCloseable` in way that it would serve *us* well, given [Java 7's `try-with-resources` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)? Or closing an `EntityManager` auto-magically is far too complicated?

Is this particular feature considered to be a part of [JSR-342](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=342)?

Comment: I think it's a good question to ask at the JPA specification mailing list here: http://java.net/projects/jpa-spec/lists

Comment: It came up on the Servlet list once. The problem is that JPA, JSF etc want to be backwards compatible outside Java EE.

Comment: If you use container-managed version of JPA, transactions indeed are gonna be started and closed as your words "auto-magically", and you dont have to worry about that. If your question is related to the application-managed version of JPA, you should edit the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're managing your own JPA objects then try-with-resources is a nice thing to have with respect to EntityManagers and to a lesser extent the EntityManagerFactory.

I opted to create a utility that wraps a EntityManagerFactory in a [java.lang.reflect.Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) that implements an [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) version of the interface. The invocation handler then intercepts calls to createEntityManager() so it can return proxied versions of the underlying EntityManager instances that also implement AutoCloseable.

I think it's much easier working in the world of container managed JPA objects but if you're stuck running in a simple webapp then this may work for you.

Comment: massfords forgot to mention that he wrote a great article where he shows how to actually create such proxy, you can find it here: http://massfords.com/Proxy-for-AutoCloseable/ . Thanks Mark!

Comment: @wpodgorski Thanks a lot! :-) But since then the link changed: https://massfords.com/2016/06/06/proxyforautocloseable/